# Accessing captured variables through explicit this parameter in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

From [declarations / functions / 9.3.4.6 / 6.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#6.2) <sup>(i apologize on how to cite the specific sentence from standard)</sup>:

> An explicit-object-parameter-declaration is a parameter-declaration with a this specifier. An explicit-object-parameter-declaration shall appear only as the first parameter-declaration of a parameter-declaration-list of either: (6.1) a member-declarator that declares a member function ([class.mem]), or (6.2) a **lambda-declarator** ([expr.prim.lambda]).

If `this` as explicit object parameter is permitted from lambda expressions, what will happen when we capture variables at the same time?

Based on my understandings, if we have lambda under the hood:

```cpp
[x = 2](this auto& func) { x = 4; }();
```

may have the rough equivalent of:

```cpp
class lambda01 {
  private:
    int x;

  public:
    constexpr lambda01(cons int& x_)
    : x{x_} {}

    constexpr void operator()(this lambda01& func) {
      func.x = 4;
    }
};
lambda04 lambda04_obj {2};
lambda04_obj.operator()();
```

if it's right.

For example no. 1:

```cpp
int x;

// is it:
[&x](this auto& func){ x = 4; }();

assert(x == 4);

// or:
[&x](this auto& func){ func.x = 2; }();

assert(x == 2);
```

- Are both expressions valid?
- Is lambda taking l-value object parameter valid?

For example no. 2 that will print arguments in variadic:

```cpp
[]<typename... Args>(const Args&... args) {
  [&](this auto func){
    /** ... **/
  };
}(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

From the commented expression, which one is valid?

- `(std::cout << args << '\n', ...)`
- `(std::cout << func.args << '\n', ...)`
- both
- neither

If the second choice is valid, then that would deserve another question regarding the possible parameter packs in 1 object.

In short, is it valid to use captured variables accessed with dot operator in lambda taking explicit object parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't allow it:

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.

If it's "unnamed", then you can't name it. There's specific language that causes the name of a captured entity to be transformed into a `this`-based expression, but that's it.

So you can take an explicit `this` parameter, and names of captured entities will automatically use that. But you can't access those variables through the explicit parameter.

The only reason to explicitly take `this` in a lambda is to use the interfaces the standard provides: calling the lambda. AKA: recursively calling the lambda *without* naming the lambda.

Comment: Other than capture of `this`, one could see extending the standard to say that the captured variables are actually private members with that name I suspect?  Then I could see adding a `public` keyword to lambda, heh.